# No puedo correr una prueba unitaria en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

Lo mas probable es que sea un detalle minúsculo pero aún así no puedo resolverlo :c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver es una clase cuyo rol es una prueba unitaria, pero a pesar de estar usando el JUnit no me da la opción para ejecutar esa clase en particular cuando aprieto <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, por ende no puedo ejecutar la prueba unitaria.

Lo curioso es que antes funcionaba con normalidad, pero ahora no se que le dió a Netbeans que no me permite ejecutar esta prueba.

Comment: Emilia, si adjuntas el código en formato texto tu pregunta quedaría mejor! :)

Comment: Si utilizas el teclado NO sería con shift+f6; sería con Ctrl+f6

Answer (score 1):

Tiene mucho que netbeans no permite correr una prueba unitaria. En su lugar tiene la opción "Test File".

Usa siempre **Test File** para ejecutar una prueba unitaria en particular o la combinación de teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>